# Playing a sound when a button is onFocus or onPress Android

Tags: android, button, onfocus

I'm making kind of a simple piano activity and I have a few buttons simulating the piano keys and I just want to play a sound; not when the button is clicked but when it is pressed.

I tried doing it on its focus status with a `OnFocusChangeListener` but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: What did you try? You should post your code instead of telling us "it didn't work".

Comment: Hi and thanks @AlexLockwood and sorry for not posting the code. I just wanted a general idea to do what i asked so i can implement my own code. I found then answer as techiServices suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off using an `ImageView` and utilising the `OnTouchListener`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using buttons why not use the `onClickListener`?  If you want a long press use the `OnLongClickListener`?

A good video using the `onLongClickListener`: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7YuusyEvOg&feature=plcp

Comment: Thanks James, the OnLongClick stuff is really interesting and fun but is not what i have on mind. I kept searching yesterday and i figured the best way to do it (since there's no onFocusListener) is to create an onTouchChange or Listener (not sure yet) and when an PRESSED_DOWN event occur play the sound... i think i will try that! Thanks!